# Questions that should be migrated to Gardening and Landscaping.

Tags: discussion, migration

Now that [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) is in beta and going quite well any question that fits their site better should really be migrated. Normally questions aren't migrated to beta sites but if they'd only be closed as off topic here then I think it's worth it.

Firstly it'll help keep our site on topic.

Secondly it'll help drive traffic to their site - always a good thing.

So if you spot any, post it in an answer here and I'll liaise with the moderators over there to see if they agree. Yes you could just flag the post, but this way we'll have the evidence to back up the need (if there is one) for a permanent migration path set up on the close dialog (**once Gardening migrates from beta**) that's accessible to all 3K+ users not just the moderators.

Comment: @Niall - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to look at tags than search for individual questions:

- The [compost](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compost) tag.  You've already got listed one: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6137/22
- Two of the [planting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planting) questions.  I'm not sure about [How to get rid of a burned coal smell that's coming to my flat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4977/22) being on-topic there; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/26 and https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1283/26.
- [fertilizer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fertilizer)
- All the [weeds](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weeds) questions except [How can I get rid of the weeds and moss growing between the paver stones in my driveway?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1072/22)
- Surprisingly few under [gardening](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) IMO (suggesting it's not a good tag):

  - https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/828/22
  - [Natural/Free Composting Liner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5866/22) (already mentioned under [compost](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compost))
  - [Non-toxic materials for edging garden](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5254/22) (maybe)
- Some questions under [lawn](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn) and [grass](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grass).  I'd look at each individually and decide.

Answer (score 1):

Questions closed that mention gardens and gardening:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/naturemill-any-suggestion

Questions migrated:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8116/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-large-cracks-in-my-lawn-due-to-the-lack-of-rain-migrate?noredirect=1

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/828/i-replanted-grass-after-my-lawn-was-damaged-but-its-very-patchy-now-what-mig?noredirect=1

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/how-to-drain-lawn-with-very-little-slope?noredirect=1

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/253/beautiful-lawn-and-weed-control-migrated?noredirect=1

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/can-anyone-help-identify-this-plant-migrated?noredirect=1

Question migrated (and subsequently deleted):

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/tips-on-planting-large-plants-migrated?noredirect=1

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/how-to-decide-what-is-the-right-watering-schedule-for-my-front-lawn-migrated?noredirect=1

Simply deleted:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/water-sprinkler-doesnt-run-but-timer-runs-fine

Comment: There was also a question about a Schefflera Arboricola that was deleted.  The same plant showed up on G&L a while ago.